# how to upload image created using php to users timeline on facebook

Tags: php, gd, facebook-apps

I have developed a facebook application that contains following files
1) index.php
2) cap3.php
where **cap3.php** generates an image using GD in PHP.
index.php displays this image  using following code

```
<img src="cap3.php">
```

now I want this generated image to be posted on user's timeline.
I have tried to do so by using following code:

```
$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$img = 'cap3.php';
$args=array( 'source' => '@' .$current , 'message' => 'Photo uploaded via!' );
$photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', $args);
```

but the image is not posted on user's timeline
please help.

Comment: What response do you get from the Facebook API ?

Comment: When you are giving a `.php` file as image source file, no code inside that file will be interpreted – this is __not__ a case of accessing that script via HTTP, so only the unparsed PHP code will get posted to Facebook, and of course they do not recognize that as a valid image file. You will either have to save that image data locally and then use that file as `source`; or you have to make the image script publicly available via HTTP and somehow (GET/Session) pass the necessary data to it, and then have Facebook read it themselves, by providing its URL as a parameter `url` instead of `source`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is to put your `cap3.php` file in your remote host to get an URL to it. For example : `http://www.example.com/cap3.php`. Then, you download that image from your app and send it to facebook.

Let's see an example:

```
$local_img = 'cap3.png'; // I assume your cap3.php generates a PNG file
$remote_img = 'http://www.example.com/cap3.php';

// sample: check for errors in your production app!
$img_content = file_get_contents($remote_img);
file_put_contents($locale_img, $img_content);

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args=array( 'source' => '@' .$locale_img , 'message' => 'Photo uploaded via!' );
$photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', $args);
```

Comment: Note : I do not know if `'source' => '@'<path>` takes a realpath or not, but you'll get the idea.